# Self-employed status in Moscow for residence card holders

Tags: taxes, residence-cards, russia

Does anyone out there have experience with this? I've got a daydream of supporting myself selling paintings or teaching drawing rather than being an English teacher forever and I've heard little hints about a supposedly very generous tax on self-employed people here. But as anyone who lives here knows, Russian bureaucracy is never easy and particularly for foreigners.

Comment: You'll probably need to elaborate on specifically what your question is, for this site.